# addEventListener: click and remove the tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, addeventlistener

Here are the details of the case I want to get some help with:

```
    <section class='result'> </section>
some tags... when the input value found/not found
```

I create an input to find some text/article, if the input value can't be found, it's gonna show:

> sorry can't found `input same value on box searching`

And then I try to click the button click again, it repeats that text again and again, when i click the `button` many times...

```
sorry can't found 'input same value on box searching'
sorry can't found 'input same value on box searching'
sorry can't found 'input same value on box searching'
sorry can't found 'input same value on box searching'
sorry can't found 'input same value on box searching'
```

Etc...

I just want it to show just once, and when the input changes, it's not gonna repeat again and it's gonna show the new different value: `sorry cant... 'new input value'`

That is when the input data can't be found, and when the input data is found, after I change the input data in the search box, I want to remove that text `sorry cant...`.

And then showing the article data after I found it...

So I want to get some help with how to not repeat them and then insert the new tag after I found the data input by DOM.

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/cornloh/d2Lgkpxe/

```js
const find = el => document.querySelector(el)
const create = el => document.createElement(el)

const lookingThem = find('.searchButton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const inputText = find('.box').value.trim(); 
  // console.log(inputText.length);
  result(inputText);
})

const result = searching => {
  const wikipedia = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&prop=info&inprop=url&utf8=&format=json&origin=*&srlimit=20&srsearch=${searching}`; // API
  fetch(wikipedia)
    .then(resolve => resolve.json())
    .then(data => {
      if(typeof data.continue === 'undefined'){
        displayCantFound(find('.box').value)
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => alert('an error occurred', e))
}

const displayCantFound = theInputValue => {
  find('.result').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
  `<div>
      <h3> sorry can't found what you are looking ${theInputValue} </h3>
  </div>`)
}

// const displayError = () => {
//
// }
```

Comment: Can you post your current Javascript? (just set a string to the input's current value, and only display the message when the new value is different)

Comment: i still working on error cant found, try type on input by `jshashfakhfhafehesf`
https://jsfiddle.net/cornloh/d2Lgkpxe/

Comment: Please post all relevant code *in the question itself* (per SO rules)

Comment: i just inserted the jsfiddle on the question

Comment: That's a *link to the code*, not the *code itself*

Comment: i just inserted it again @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't insert new html every time. Just completly replace it.

```
const displayCantFound = theInputValue => {
  find('.result').innerHTML  = `<div>
      <h3> sorry can't found what you are looking ${theInputValue} </h3>
  </div>`
}
```

If you want error to be removed when the data is found you can replace the following part of code with mine

```
if(typeof data.continue === 'undefined'){
   displayCantFound(find('.box').value)
} else {
   console.log(data);
   //this line is added
   document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: so if the data found , will it change the innerhtml?? and the error message, gonna be deleted ??

Comment: @koplweou i have edited the answer for your second purpose(removing error if the data is found). Accept answer if you are satisfied

Comment: hmmmm nice idea